# Why does my mesh become bigger when using an object offset on the Array modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to use an array w/ an object offset, but when I align my origin with the empty my mesh become bigger [image: This happend when I use the Object offset]

[image: After I change the origin]

I don't know if I made something wrong or it's a bug in blender...
I'm Using the version 2.83

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do... if the mesh is too big just scale it down.

Comment: hard to understand, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Because you rescaled your object. Apply the scale on the mesh and on the empty. (Ctrl+A)

Comment: It worked, thanks!